# does here maps javascript api support passive listeners?

Tags: here-api

I'm using the here maps javascript api, and certain event listeners are bogging the system down, and I don't seem to be able to make those listeners passive - is it possible to do so?

In Chrome, after putting some polylines on the map along with certain eventListeners, I see many warnings of this sort

```
[Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 335ms
```

... when I developer tools to reveal what might be causing performance problems (by checking "scrolling performance issues" in the Rendering tab), I see that a "mousewheel event listener" is causing problems.

How can I get these events to be passive (which I'm hoping/expecting will remove the jank I'm experiencing)?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid those warnings appearing regarding events on multiple objects on the map at once the recommendation is to use an ***H.map.Group***

That way you can assign the events you need to the ***H.map.Group*** and all the objects within it will have access to that event for their own use.

In the same way, if you need to add different types of objects to that group and each one will have a different event, you can add those events to each object separately before or after being added to the ***H.map.Group*** and once that is done, you can add the ***H.map.Group*** to map.

In this link you can find more information about it:

**H.map.Group:** https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.32.0/api_reference/H.map.Group.html

**Example:** https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/events/map-object-events-displayed